# How do you link two entities together

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I'm using ABP and am not understanding how I'm supposed to link two entities together.
For example linking an Author to a Book. Here is a list of changes I have made. My goal is to have the Book modal dialog show a list of Authors to select in the Create modal dialog (from there I can easily infer what to do next for edit and such).

I added AuthorId (as AuthorId) as well as AuthorDto (as Author) and while I can get swagger to show that it has an AuthorId (guid) and an Author (as well as enumerates, correctly, what an Author is -- all this under the Get request (which pulls the list of books)) -- I can't get the Author to actually popular in it.

I assume it's my job to map it correctly and I would have thought that belonged in the BookAppService. I would further assume that ti's BookAppService.GetListAsync and I'm supposed to populate / modify it accordingly but the repository doesn't seem to let me and I assume I'm not supposed to make a brand new dbContext?

The documentation for the next generation of ABP isn't finished so I'm not quite sure where to implement this (I'm choosing this generation as one to practice and learn since none of the stuff I'm doing is of importance and this is a learning experience more than anything else).

I'm not quite sure what to do here at this point. Thoughts?

Comment: This is one of my biggest issues with junk like ABP. Instead of learning the actual ASP.NET Core framework, which would have limitless value, you're spinning your wheels learning some layer (and not even a good one at that). Especially if you're just starting out, stick with the base framework. You likely won't need anything else anyways.

Comment: I'm not just starting out. The origin of this was my Reddit post where I wanted to have a new template. I've learned a great deal from ABP however if you have any other suggestions, I'm open. I can do, close enough, with the base framework however when it comes to security, caching, or other areas -- I'm ignorant in.

Comment: To be specific -- I wanted a more thorough starting template. The website abp.io points to go here for any questions instead of hosting forums. It ha a tutorial and explains well but the tutorial / getting starting isn't completed yet. It recommends using the older stuff (which works well enough) but I'm more focused on ASP.NET Core instead and I'm in no particular rush. So I'd rather spend my time learning the newer stuff and educating myself in that direction. Thoughts?